# R: How to properly offset yearquarter labels for daily data in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a simple plot using yearquarter labels instead of raw dates, to show how the development of a value changes over the quarters. However, when trying to format the YQ labels, they seem to have some offset as they do not start properly. See the code and the figure

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

(df_Example <- tibble(Date = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day"),
                     Value = 1))
#> # A tibble: 731 x 2
#>    Date       Value
#>    <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 2019-01-01     1
#>  2 2019-01-02     1
#>  3 2019-01-03     1
#>  4 2019-01-04     1
#>  5 2019-01-05     1
#>  6 2019-01-06     1
#>  7 2019-01-07     1
#>  8 2019-01-08     1
#>  9 2019-01-09     1
#> 10 2019-01-10     1
#> # ... with 721 more rows

ggplot(data = df_Example, aes(x = Date, y = Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months",
               labels = function(x) format.yearqtr(x, "%Y Q%q"))
```

[image]

As should be clear in the figure, the line starts before the labelling starts. I would very much like these two to be aligned.

Comment: You need to set `breaks` specifically, instead of `date_breaks`: in this plot, the x-axis breaks are defined started at `"2018-11-25"`, not at the beginning of a quarter, so your ticks won't like up where you expect them to.

Comment: I see! I've worked it around by defining `breaks = seq(min(df_Example$Date), max(df_Example$Date), by = "3 months")`. Is it etiquette to leave it here as a comment, or should I post this as an answer?

Comment: @r2evans Also, do you happen to know why or maybe where I can find how the code selects `2018-11-25` as the starting date?

Comment: It's part of `expand=` in the `scale_*` functions. If you don't want expansion, set it manually. See `?expansion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)      # as.yearqtr, as.POSIXct.yearqtr
qtr1 <- function(by) {
  function(x) {
    xqtr <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(as.yearqtr(x)))
    seq(xqtr[1], xqtr[2], by = by)
  }
}
ggplot(data = df_Example, aes(x = Date, y = Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = qtr1("3 months"),
               labels = function(x) zoo::format.yearqtr(x, "%Y Q%q"))
```

[image: ggplot2 with more controller axis ticks]

Note:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23046072/3358272 suggests that at some point we could have just done

  ```r
  as.Date(as.yearqtr(..))
  ```

  but that doesn't appear to work. The `as.Date(as.POSIXct(as.yearqtr(.)))` was to work around this.

Comment: Very nice, thanks so much! One last question about the syntax: is the passing of functions limited to work for calls such as `scale_x_...`, as it somehow(?) reads the main `x` aesthetic mapping? Or am I misinterpreting what the function (even the format function for `labels`) is applied on?

Comment: `scale_x_*` gets the range of values, optionally expanded, from the `x=` aesthetic. With no expansion, it should literally be `range(df_Example$Date)` here; but since the default expansion is not 0, it is a little more than that. To your scale call, add the argument `expand = expansion(0,0)`. That does not necessarily solve the problem that `2019 Q1` many not be aligned with the first day of the quarter, though, unless you strictly control that in the data. If you do that, my `qtr1` breaks function may still be useful (or necessary), it should never do harm.